# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate

Tags: java, dynamic, jasper-reports, report

I am trying to get a Dynmic Report to work with the following code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.column.Columns;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.component.Components;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.datatype.DataTypes;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.HorizontalAlignment;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.exception.DRException;
/**
 *
 * @author Nigel Backhurst
 */
public class UnsoldLots
{
    private Connection con;
    private Seller seller;
    private int auctionID;

    public UnsoldLots(Connection c, Seller s, int a)
    {
        con = c;
        seller = s;
        auctionID = a;
        String sellerName = seller.FirstName + " " + seller.Surname;
        String sellerID = seller.idSeller;
        String auction = Integer.toString(a);
        String sql = "SELECT LotNumber, Description FROM lots WHERE "
               +  "AuctionID = \'" + auction + "\' AND idSellers = \'"
               +  sellerID + "\' AND LotSold = \'F\'";
        String rTitle = "Unsold Lots for " + sellerName;
        JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
         //create a new report
         report
        .columns(
                Columns.column("Lot", "LotNumber", DataTypes.integerType()),
                Columns.column("Description", "Description", DataTypes.stringType())
            )
            .title(
            //title of the report
            Components.text(rTitle )
            .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
            .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())
            .setDataSource( sql , con);
          try 
          {
            //show the report
            report.show();
          } catch (DRException e) 
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } 


    }
}
```

However, I get the following exception when I run the code and cannot work out why:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.component.DRList.setType(DRList.java:80)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.component.DRList.<init>(DRList.java:52)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.DRBand.<init>(DRBand.java:44)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.DRReport.init(DRReport.java:144)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.DRReport.<init>(DRReport.java:126)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.ReportBuilder.<init>(ReportBuilder.java:75)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.<init>(JasperReportBuilder.java:117)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.report(DynamicReports.java:120)
    at iea.auction.manager.UnsoldLots.<init>(UnsoldLots.java:45)
```

I suspect I might be missing an include but cannot work out which.

Comment: What does NoClassDefFoundError indicate?

Answer (score 1):

You miss the `commons-lang3.jar` in your classpath. Download and add it to your classpath.